# How to Install AD LDS on a Windows 10 Machine

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

I have a document with a supporting [link](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/07/12/getting-started-with-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services.aspx) that others have used to install this on Windows 7 and that works great.  But I get a message when I try to run the **Windows6.1-KB975541-x64.msu** on my Windows 10 laptop.

> Installer encountered an error: 0x80096002
>
> The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid or not found.

I do have `Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services` enabled in the Windows Features and did a reboot. Did some searching out there and did not find anything to help me on Windows 10.  Things I did try did not work.  Is there a newer version of AD LDS for Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

The standalone installer is only necessary for Windows 7.

As you mentioned, the supported way to install AD LDS on Windows 8 and Windows 10 is via the **Turn Windows Features on or off** dialog.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582849/ldap-server-for-development-purposes-on-windows-8

Comment: Thank you for the reply, seeing it is 2 years later I actually do not even have that machine anymore and do not need to deal with AD LDS.  Hopefully it helps someone else.